# Sequelize.js Count associated table attributes

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Hi I'm trying to fetch all projects along with number of members assigned to the project.
So its working fine, **but I also want some attributes in the projectMember table. Only one is working either the count or the attributes, is there a way to do both ?**

```
project = await Project.findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.and]: [
            { status: { [Op.ne]: 99 } },
            { '$workspace.company_id$': { [Op.eq]: companyId } },
        ]
    },

    attributes: {
        include: [
            [sequelize.fn("COUNT", sequelize.col("projectMember.user_id")), "memberCount"],
        ]
    },

    include: [
        {
            model: ProjectMember,
            as: 'projectMember',
            required: false,
            attributes: []
        },
        {
            model: Workspace,
            as: 'workspace',
            attributes: []
        }
    ],

    group: ['project_master.id']
})
```

Comment: This is not good approach, this query gets slow overtime because you always run COUNT operation for every project in table (more projects and members -> slower query), you should save project members count as a column in projects and then just query it along with other attributes. Never make aggregations on included models.